# Python - "I/O operation on closed file" when there is no file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am writing a web crawler in Python using Selenium that goes to a page, grabs the source code for the page, presses a JavaScript button to go to the next page and then repeats.  When I run my code, it launches Firefox and navigates all of the pages, however when it finishes and tries to do anything with the contents of the pages, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\crawler.py", line 24, in test_pull
    print(contents)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The code that I am trying to execute is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
import sys,io
from Parser import HTMLParser

class TestPull(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
       self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
       self.base_url = "some_url"
       self.verificationErrors = []
       self.accept_next_alert = True

   def test_pull(self):
       driver = self.driver
       driver.get(self.base_url)
       contents = "" 
       num = 1
       valid = 1
       while valid == 1:
          num += 1
          contents += driver.page_source

          if self.is_element_present(By.ID, "contentright_3_next_page") == True:
              driver.find_element_by_id("contentright_3_next_page").click()
          else: 
              valid = 0

       parser = HTMLParser()
       parser.feed(contents)

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

If I remove the print statement, the output is still:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\crawler.py", line 36, in test_pull
    parser.feed(contents)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\html\parser.py", line 165, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\html\parser.py", line 222, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\html\parser.py", line 413, in parse_starttag
    self.handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "C:\Users\...\crawler.py", line 20, in handle_starttag
    print(attrs[1][1])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

My parser is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import sys,io

text_file = open("output.txt", "w")

class HTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            if attrs[0][0] == 'title':
                print(attrs[1][1])
                text_file.write(str(attrs[1][1]) + '\n')
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        ''' if tag == 'a':
        print(HTMLParser.getpos(self))
        print("Encountered a end tag:", tag)'''
    def handle_data(self, data):
        '''print("Encountered some data  :", data)'''

    text_file.close()
```

I have searched for a solution to this error, every question I could find were relating to a file that was open, closed (either in a for/while loop), and then they tried to access/write to the file.  I have made changes to my code so it is writing to a single string (instead of writing to a text file) and then running the batch of source code through my parser, it still gives me this error.

I don't think that there should be a file to be closed and I don't think the contents string should cause this conflict (though I am still fairly new to python and do not know all the nuances of the language yet).  Could someone explain what is happening and how I could correct this?

Comment: please provide more context (code). is it possible that you somewhere redefine sys.stdout?

Comment: Updated with more of the code.  Yes I do, this was to fix an issue with some codec and unicode issues.

Comment: Can you show us `crawler.py`?  It's definitely a problem with your `sys.stdout` redirect, but it'd be good to see what's happening around the actual exception point as well.

Comment: Added the parser.py and added the rest of TestPull.  I don't know if it will help, but it was breaking before it got the call of parser.

Comment: replacing `sys.stdout` is sketchy.  I suggest not overwriting that, and handling the UTF8 issues before moving ahead.

Comment: After removing the [sys.stout] redirect and handling the UTF8 issues, I replaced the string with a file and it seems to work.  Thank you guys so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import sys,io

class HTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            if attrs[0][0] == 'title':
                print(attrs[1][1])
                with open('output.txt', 'w') as text_file:
                    text_file.write(str(attrs[1][1]) + '\n')
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        ''' if tag == 'a':
        print(HTMLParser.getpos(self))
        print("Encountered a end tag:", tag)'''
    def handle_data(self, data):
        '''print("Encountered some data  :", data)'''

    text_file.close()
```